# Tools for apache cordova ctp 3.2 package failed

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I install visual studio update 5,then uninstall tools for apache cordova ctp 3, after finishing my update for VS I reinstall the tools for apache cordova ctp3.2 which is compatible with the update 5,but the problem is when the installation complete it give error " tools for apache cordova package failed ", all packages are installed unless this, so how can i fix it??